# Interstitials ads fail to load on real test

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using Interstitials ads on my app. I get test ads while using this code below:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("CCC40F2DAEXXXXXXXXXX5DCB16FDDE10").build();
```

I don't get any ads when I request ads using this code below.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Here is the errors I get.

```
04-04 20:56:48.620: W/ResourceType(27563): Requesting resource 0x7f0b000e failed because it is complex
04-04 20:56:48.620: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27563): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
04-04 20:56:48.625: W/ResourceType(27563): Requesting resource 0x7f0b000e failed because it is complex
04-04 20:56:48.625: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27563): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
04-04 20:56:48.880: I/Ads(27563): No fill from ad server.
04-04 20:56:48.880: W/Ads(27563): Failed to load ad: 3
04-04 20:56:48.880: E/SQLiteLog(27563): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
04-04 20:56:48.880: E/SQLiteLog(27563): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) -
```

Comment: It appears the app tried to load an add but failed

Answer (score 1):

There is not always an ad available. That's why it's a good idea to use mediation to ensure you always have an ad.

```
04-04 20:56:48.880: I/Ads(27563): No fill from ad server.
```

This log line tells you that no ad was available.

Comment: What do you mean by mediation?

Comment: A mediator will let you serve ads from multiple ad networks. See https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2413211